# Lazy touchpad on Ubuntu after suspend. “SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad” disappears from the xinput list

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, suspend

I am using an HP ProBook 440 G6 laptop and before a suspend, the touchpad works perfectly. But after a suspend it becomes much less sensitive and very lazy.

Here is output of xinput list command:

```
Virtual core pointer                       id=2
 - Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4
 - SYNA3082:00 06CB:8265 Touchpad             id=10
 - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                 id=12
```

After suspend the `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` entry disappears and modprobe doesn't help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to be fixed at least in 5.5.5-200.fc31.x86_64 kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently solved this on my HP ProBook 430 G6.
One solution is to reload the **i2c_hid** kernel module after resuming from a suspend.

```
modprobe -r i2c_hid # remove the i2c_hid kernel module
modprobe i2c_hid # add the i2c_hid kernel module
```

This can be automated. For example, on systems using systemd a script can be added to the directory /lib/systemd/system-sleep/. Below is the content of the script I use (/lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad-fix.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = 'post' ]; then
    modprobe -r i2c_hid && modprobe i2c_hid
fi
```

You will likely need to be **root** to write the script to this location. Additionally make sure that the script is executable:

```
chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad-fix.sh
```